# Lerna, Storybook - Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, storybook, lerna, monorepo

I want to setup monorepo for my front-end and back-end. Till now have setup front-end inside the package with storybook. When I run `npm run storybook` (storybook), code Compiles and automatically opens Browser. But I'm not able to see the Storybook and I'm getting the following Error

[image]

#### Root package.json

```
{
  "name": "turbotic-platform",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "",
  "scripts": {
    "bootstrap": "lerna bootstrap",
    "reset": "rm -rf node_modules && lerna clean",
    "build": "lerna run build",
    "start": "lerna run start --parallel",
    "pt": "prettier --write 'packages/**/*.{js,html,scss,tsx,ts,jsx}'"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Turbotic",
  "license": "ISC",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "lerna": "^3.20.2",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

#### lerna.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "npmClient": "npm"
}
```

#### front-end package.json

```
{
  "name": "client-turbotic-dashboard",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.0.27",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.0.27",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.0.27",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.0.27",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^3.1.4",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.0.27",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "react-is": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

#### Folder Structure

[image]

It works when I use `npmClient:"yarn"` with `useWorkspaces: true` but I want to use `npmClient:"npm"`

Comment: Have you found any solution for this?

Comment: @VivekShah not yet!

Comment: Oh, that's sad. So have you used any workaround for this?

Comment: @VivekShah I used `npmClient:"yarn"` and `useWorkspaces:true` from then

Comment: Could you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
  "useWorkspaces":true
```

in your lerna.json and put this code in package.json:

```
"workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
]
```